# Difference between GIS mapping and Photogrammetric mapping

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, photogrammetry

I can't seem to understand both type of mapping. I am planning to make a drone for mapping and I am confused about picking one. My purpose is to take photos of specific area and do 3D modeling of that area into the software.

Comment: I don't think there is a term like "gis" mapping. I believe you mean photogrammetry

Comment: @Geof Are they same?

Comment: GIS can be used to make maps and the data source of layers in those maps may come from photogrammetry.